# Linear Algebra - matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

solve the following matrix equation for $X$:

$$ A(X-B)^{-1}=B$$ where

$$A = \left [\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2  \\
3 & 4  \\
\end{array} \right ]$$
$$B = \left [\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1  \\
1 & 3  \\
\end{array} \right ]$$

How I solved it:

$$A= B(X-B) \implies   A= BX-B^2 \implies   X = (A+B^2)B^{-1}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, but are off by a little bit. First, it is important to point out that $B$ is invertible because it is has a non-zero determinant. Then from the line $$A=B(X-B)=BX-B^2$$ you have to *add* $B^2$ to both sides to get $$A+B^2=BX$$ From here, you can multiply $B^{-1}$ (since we know it exists) to the left hand side, not the right hand side to get a final answer of  $$B^{-1}(A+B^2)=X$$ It does matter which side you multiply on, because we don't know that $B$ or $B^{-1}$ can commute with $X$.

Comment: Surely we have $A(X-B)^{-1}=B \implies A=B(X-B) \implies A = BX - B^2$?

Comment: Your a hero, thank you very much <3

Comment: @Unochiii surely you are correct ;) Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @hussi no problem, but Unochiii pointed out one place I did make a mistake. The answer should be correct now that I've edited it.

Comment: so its not B^−1(A+B)=X?  uh nvm i see it now :)

Comment: X −B = (A^−1B)^−1 = B^−1A ⇔ X = B^−1A + B. that what my teacher wrote :(, so i think ur first answer was correct

Comment: Are you sure the starting equation was correct? If so, you will get to the line $B(X-B)$, which is definitely equal to $BX-B^2$

Comment: If you take $X=B^{-1}(A+B)$, you will find that $X-B$ is not invertible.

Comment: @hussi: Your teacher has adopted a different method of solution there, by which $$A(X-B)^{-1}=B \iff (X-B)^{-1}=A^{-1}B \iff X-B=(A^{-1}B)^{-1} = B^{-1}A \iff X = B^{-1}A + B$$ If you expand out graydad's answer, you will notice that $X = B^{-1}(A+B^2) = B^{-1}A + B$, so the two are compatible.

Something to note is that $B^{-1}A + B$ and $B^{-1}(A+B)$ are not in general the same matrix.